# Does using Checkstyle Plugin for use within large multimodule projects require a separate project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I went through https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html to configure checkstyle plugin for multi-module projects. This requires creating a separate project just to house the resources which could be hardly 4-5 files(at least in my case). Can't I just keep those files inside a resources folder in parent-project? Will those files be available on the classpath of every inheriting child?

In simple terms, I don't want to create a separate project just to hold a few files (if this doesn't make any difference)

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to create a separate project to house the checkstyle resources.  Those resources house the checkstyle rules that need to be available to the plugin when it runs.  Putting the checkstyle rules into its own project, and then adding them as a dependency is just the most convenient way of accomplishing this.  Of course you can have every project have its own copy of the checkstyle runs.

If you put it in the parent project then that could work.  If the project is packaged as a jar.

Comment: In my case parent is a **pom** packaged project. All children are also modules of it. So I want to specify the checkstyle only in the parent and want it to be executed during the parent's build on every child.